# Static Formulas in Excel

Tags: excel, static, formula, countif

I have a formula in excel that looks like such: `=COUNTIF(Imports!$B$2:$B$999,"1")`

It works like I want it to but part of my manipulation of the spreadsheet requires me to insert new columns in the sheet that formula is referencing.  When I do that it changes the formula from column B to column C which is actually not what I want.  I want it to reference column B no matter what.  How would I achieve this in Excel? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `INDIRECT` to reference range from its text address:

```
=COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Imports!$B$2:$B$999"),"1")
```